# Simple GUI operation in Qt

Tags: qt4, qt-creator

I know this is very basic question but I am new to QT thats why asking this question.

In QT, I have a `QLineEdit` and a `QPushButton`. I want to set **hello** to the `QLineEdit` on the click of `QPushButton`. I am able to go to the click slot of the push button.

Also how to go to paint() slot of any widget.(I am not finding the paint() in the goto slot dialog.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to "go to paint()" slot? There is no such slot in QWidget. What do you mean by "go to click slot of the push button". If you want to change text call simply setText on line edit. Everything will be repainted

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:

```
void Foo::on_button1_clicked()
{
    lineedit1->setText( "hello" );
}
```

Remember to declare `on_button1_clicked` as a slot in the header file.